# how to write data from an input field to a progress tag

Tags: javascript, html

I was having a problem, I'm usually pretty adept at js (but sometimes things tend to fall out of my head) This is not one of my finest hours, I'm using the html5 progress element for the first time, read the w3 docs, but they didn't really help, I'll give you my code, can you tell me whats wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<progress id="myProgress" value="75" max="100">
</progress>

<hr>
<input type ="text" id="myTextarea"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">write to progress</button>
<hr>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("myProgress").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `document.getElementById("myProgress").value = x;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `value` attribute of the progress bar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<progress id="myProgress" value="75" max="100">
</progress>

<hr>
<input type ="text" id="myTextarea"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">write to progress</button>
<hr>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanx so much @DavidDomain im gonna upvote u because this is the easiest answer for anyone who visits this page.